# PyGame Main Menu

Tags: python, pygame

So, i have a school project and it is to create a game. I've created the game, but we need to have a main menu also. I'm fairly new to PyGame and don't have a clue on how to do it. I'm  also fairly new to some aspects of programming, such as classes. In my program i have my main file name "Computer Science Game.py" and i want my main menu in another file. I then want my main menu, when i click play to load the "Computer Science Game.py" file. I have no idea how to do this. Also PyGame isn't really good for making Main Menus i've spent hours researching, but to no avail, could some one just give me a start, that i could expand please? Thanks
P.S. This is my first time using StackOverflow so please excuse any mistakes :)

Comment: Okay, so I searched "pygame menu" in Google, and the first link brought me to [this page](http://www.pygame.org/tags/menu) on the pygame website. The [first link on that listing](http://www.pygame.org/project-menu_key-2278-.html) takes you to a page where you can download the source for an example application with a menu implemented using pygame. Does that help?

Comment: See, as i'm new-ish to Python, i've tried that and i got confused :/

Comment: Did you try downloading the source and looking at it (this includes reading the comments)? What you're asking for here is for someone to write example code for a pygame menu, which is unnecessary because example code is already available.

Comment: I have and i still get confused. Also, i apologise if i came across like that, but i'm just looking for a starter, so i know where to start.

Comment: I would recommend taking smaller steps. Forget pygame for awhile, and just make sure you understand how to split up a python program into multiple python files, testing with prints and `raw_input`. Once you understand that, work on making a PyGame menu in a single file. Once you understand that as well, combine your knowledge together. Come back to StackOverflow when you have code that you have written that you think should work, but doesn't. Make sure you show the relevant parts of your code, and explain what you're trying to do, what you're expecting to happen, and what actually happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not going to completely code out how to write a menu for you, because that would defeat the purpose of the class exercize, but I can point you in the right direction.

How I would go about writing the main menu would be the following assuming that you have a two option menu: quit and start game (pseudo code):

```
initialize all menu variables

draw menu pix and selections

while a selection has not been made:
    look for key inputs (arrow keys/enter/esc)
        if down arrow pressed:
            move selection box to next option and note that the selection is on the next object down
        if up arrow pressed:
            move selection box to previous option and note that the selection is on the previous object up
        if escape pressed:
            quit the game
        if enter pressed:
            process which option in the menu was highlighted (quit of quit was selected, etc) and tell the while loop to stop

    update the display

set up the game variables and such

main while loop
    run the game and get an A+
```

Please let me know if this answers your question. The basic idea behind it is that you add another while loop that shows a basic menu and displays it before it moves onto the game. This might not be the most efficient way, but to me it seems like the simplest way to do things.

By the way, you may wish to stay away from things like complex animations and using mouse events for right now, until you have the basic menu figured out. Stick with good old fashioned boxes and `rect.move` on arrow key input.

Comment: not to sound like a beggar but please feel free to leave an upvote/check mark. ;) Also let me know if you need help with specific code I'd be more than happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some handy functions I use for things such as menus:

```
# `pos` is the `x,y` from `event.pos`
# x, y is the x/y co-ords from the x/y where you render a button
# x1, y1 is the width/height for the button.
# This function will return true if the button is clicked on.

def button_check(pos, x, y, x1, y1): 
    return pos[0] >= x and pos[0] < x + x1 and pos[1] >= y and pos[1] < y + y1

# This function will create a nice button with text in it.
# `sufrace` is like the default 'DISPLAYSURF', `color` is the color of the box
# `text_color` is the color of the text in the box
# `x/y` are the co-ords of the button. `width/height` are the dimensions of button
# `text` is the text for the label.

def make_button(surface,color,text_color,x,y,width,height,text):
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (0,0,0),(x-1,y-1,width+2,height+2),1) #makes outline around the box
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, color,(x,y,width,height))#mkes the box

    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial Black', 15) #creates the font, size 15 (you can change this)
    label = myfont.render(text, 1, text_color) #creates the label
    surface.blit(label, (x+2, y)) #renders the label



#example of use:
menu_items = ['Play','Load','Volume','High Scores','Exit']
while True:
    for i in range(len(menu_items)-1):#goes through each item
        make_button(DISPLAYSURF,SILVER,BLACK,10,10+(20*i),120,menu_items[i]) #puts the item into the make_button, `+20*i` will make each item 15px down from the last.

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == 5:
            if event.button == 1:
                for i in range(len(menu_items)-1):#check every button

                    if button_check(event.pos,10,10+(20*i),120):
                        if i == 0:
                            play()
                        elif i == 1:
                            load()
                        elif i == 4:
                            pygame.quit()
                            sys.exit()
```

Comment: I haven't test this myself. I'll do in a sec